# Get Facebook Events Anonymously

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

**Goal:**

I would like to list a Facebook page's events on its corresponding website.

**Issue:**

I can get the relevant data using FB's Graph API Explorer, but it does not work within the context of an external website due to FB permissions.

The reality is that I don't need access to any individual account, just to that particular FB page's events, so requiring users to log and grant permission is counterproductive.

Is this possible? Or is there a way to make the events publicly accessible?

Thanks in advance.

FYI: I'm using the FB PHP SDK.

Comment: I'm not sure enough of this to give it as an answer, but would logging in as yourself or a page from the server to get your events work?

Comment: Yes, it would. The challenge is that not everyone accessing this site uses FB, so they wouldn't be able to see the events.

Comment: As far as I can tell, Facebook's "public" means "accessible to any Facebook user" not "accessible to anyone on the internet." As such, you need to be authenticated to access public events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. register your website as an application in FB
2. Grant YOURSELF access to YOUR FB Page through YOUR Website
3. Log in to FB with the OAuth token for yourself
4. read out the public events and show that to arbitrary users on the
   net, regardless whether they have FB or not.

The trick is, that YOU are accessing FB as a FB User through your app.

Remark: probably this violates some of their legal terms of FB since you are sharing FB internal Information to everyone one the net, see the  George Cummins comments!